# TypeError: 'int' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
some_id = 1

cursor.execute('
    SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
    FROM "Indicator" 
    WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" =   %s;', some_id)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object does not support indexing
```

some_id is an int but I'd like to select indicators that have some_id = 1 (or whatever # I decide to put in the variable).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
cursor.execute('
    SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
    FROM "Indicator" 
    WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" =   %s;', [some_id])
```

This turns the `some_id` parameter into a list, which is indexable.  Assuming your method works like i think it does, this should work.

The error is happening because somewhere in that method, it is probably trying to iterate over that input, or index directly into it. Possibly like this: `some_id[0]`

By making it a list (or iterable), you allow it to index into the first element like that.

You could also make it into a tuple by doing this: `(some_id,)` which has the advantage of being immutable.

Answer (score 46):

You should pass query parameters to [`execute()`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) as a tuple (an iterable, strictly speaking), `(some_id,)` instead of `some_id`:

```
cursor.execute('
    SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
    FROM "Indicator" 
    WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" =   %s;', (some_id,))
```

Comment: The comma makes ALL the difference. Didn't realize a single item tuple doesn't turn into a tuple without a comma...

Answer (score 15):

Your id needs to be some sort of iterable for mogrify to understand the input, here's the relevant quote from the [frequently asked questions documentation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html):

```
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", "bar")    # WRONG
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar"))  # WRONG
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ("bar",)) # correct
>>> cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)", ["bar"])  # correct
```

This should work:

```
some_id = 1

cursor.execute('
    SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
    FROM "Indicator" 
    WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" =   %s;', (some_id, ))
```

Answer (score -1):

Slightly similar error when using **Django**:

```
TypeError: 'RelatedManager' object does not support indexing
```

This doesn't work

```
mystery_obj[0].id
```

This works:

```
mystery_obj.all()[0].id
```

Basically, the error reads `Some type xyz doesn't have an __ iter __ or __next__ or next function, so it's not next(), or itsnot[indexable], or iter(itsnot)`, in this case the arguments to `cursor.execute` would need to implement iteration, most commonly a `List`, `Tuple`, or less commonly an `Array`, or some custom iterator implementation.

In this specific case the error happens when the classic string interpolation goes to fill the `%s`, `%d`, `%b` string formatters.

Related:

- [How to implement __iter__(self) for a container object (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019971/how-to-implement-iter-self-for-a-container-object-python)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and it worked when I used normal formatting.

```
cursor.execute(f'
    SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
    FROM "Indicator" 
    WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" ={some_id};')
```

Comment: using formatted strings makes your database vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Answer (score -2):

Pass parameter into a list, which is indexable.

```py
cur.execute("select * from tableA where id =%s",[parameter])
```

Comment: This solution is already provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18345864/5320906) from 2013.

Answer (score -2):

Specify the vars= argument that might work:

```
cursor.execute("
          SELECT "Indicator"."indicator" 
          FROM "Indicator" 
          WHERE "Indicator"."some_id" = %s', vars=[id] )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).