# How to get only specific rows on DB, when date range fits SQL condition on a 'tsrange' datatype?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I've been struggling for hours to solve this problem, but I can't find any solution for it:

**What do I want:**

I am trying to perform a SQL request to my postgres DB. I want to get some rows of it, which matches with a given date range by using **tsrange** in my DB table.

> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/rangetypes.html

**What do I have:**

This is the content of my table '**example**'

```
ID  time_interval                                  x_value  y_value  z_value
1   ["2005-11-02 17:00:00","2005-11-02 17:20:58"]  10       20       96
2   ["2007-03-07 14:35:17","2007-03-07 14:35:17"]  2        4        7
3   ["2007-04-08 20:19:17","2007-04-08 20:32:40"]  85       74       63
4   ["2012-01-07 08:07:08","2012-01-07 09:18:00"]  92       100      863
5   ["2007-06-09 16:17:36","2007-06-09 16:39:20"]  35       758      30
```

**Data type of the table above:**

This is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.example
(
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
   time_interval tsrange,
   x_value integer,
   y_value integer,
   z_value integer
);

CREATE INDEX time_interval_idx ON public.example USING gist(time_interval);
```

**What I tried:**

This is actually my python code that I am using for performing request to my DB:

```
start_time = iso8601.parse_date("2007-02-01T00:00:00Z").replace(tzinfo=None)
end_time = iso8601.parse_date("2007-07-01T00:00:00Z").replace(tzinfo=None)

sql_statement = """SELECT id, time_interval, x_value, y_value, z_value FROM examples WHERE %s && time_interval;"""
with get_db().cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor) as cursor:
     cursor.execute(sql_statement, (psycopg2.extras.DateTimeRange(start_time, end_time, "[)")))
     my_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

This error shows, when **cursor.execute()** is trying to perform the request:

```
TypeError: 'DateTimeRange' object does not support indexing
```

I would have expect, that my code would work when I did this, which obviously not did:

```
CREATE INDEX time_interval_idx ON public.example USING gist(time_interval);
```

**What did / would work?**

This is an example to get rows from DB, when value matches **z_value**:

```
SELECT id, time_interval, x_value, y_value, z_value FROM example WHERE z_value >= 60;
```

This is my result:

```
ID  time_interval                                  x_value  y_value  z_value
1   ["2005-11-02 17:00:00","2005-11-02 17:20:58"]  10       20       96
3   ["2007-04-08 20:19:17","2007-04-08 20:32:40"]  85       74       63
4   ["2012-01-07 08:07:08","2012-01-07 09:18:00"]  92       100      863
```

Something like this works fine.

**My goal:**

If everything works, then I would expect a solution like this, when using tsrange comparison:

```
ID  time_interval                                  x_value  y_value  z_value
2   ["2007-03-07 14:35:17","2007-03-07 14:35:17"]  2        4        7
3   ["2007-04-08 20:19:17","2007-04-08 20:32:40"]  85       74       63
5   ["2007-06-09 16:17:36","2007-06-09 16:39:20"]  35       758      30
```

This is my situation right now. I hope you can help me.
Maybe I misunderstood something, but if so then please let me know it.
But also let me know, when you need more information for something.

For any help I would be so grateful!

Comment: [I think you may just need](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18345825/typeerror-int-object-does-not-support-indexing) `cursor.execute(sql, [param])` or `cursor.execute(sql, (param,))` (note the comma). I'm not a python expert though.

Comment: Wait, what? Unbelievable, this really worked! I just missed a comma after the param. Was it really that easy? Anyway, could you please post an answer so that I can accept it / mark it as solved :D?

Comment: I think we can safely redirect future users to the linked question, as it seems exact answers are there (including reasoning).