# __getitem__ overloading in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand the operator overloading in python and I have written a small programs which overloads `__getitem__()` method and calls a for loop:

```
class Ovl:
    data = [1,2,3,4,5]
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return "Hiii"

x=Ovl()

for item in x:
    print item
```

This program goes in to a infinite for loop printing "Hiii". I would like to know the reason behind it.

Comment: btw, there are other, similar cases where overriding some magic members and others not leads to an infinite loop: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61287328/2828064

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to the [`object.__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) NOTE,

> NOTE: `for` loops expect that **an `IndexError` will be raised** for illegal indexes to **allow proper detection of the end of the sequence**.

```
>>> class Ovl:
...     data = [1,2,3,4,5]
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...         if index >= 5:
...             raise IndexError('End')
...         return "Hiii"
...
>>> x=Ovl()
>>>
>>> for item in x:
...     print item
...
Hiii
Hiii
Hiii
Hiii
Hiii
```

Answer (score 4):

The overloading of `__getitem__` actually lets you do something like this:

```
>>> x = Ovl()
>>> x[6]
'Hi'
>>> x[8]
'Hi'
```

If you want to implement iterating over your class with `for`, you need to overload `__iter__` method (see here: [How to implement __iter__(self) for a container object (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019971/how-to-implement-iter-self-for-a-container-object-python)).

The reason for your loop running infinite thing is that the default implementation of `__iter__` apparently calls `__getitem__` internally. Actually, your for loop calls `__getitem__(0)`, `__getitem__(1)`, `__getitem__(2)`, `...` sequentially, so it seems to run infinite.

If you would modify your `__getitem__` method:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    return index, "Hi"
```

You can see exactly what's happening:

```
>>> x = Ovl()
>>> for item in x:
    print item 

(0, 'Hi')
(1, 'Hi')
(2, 'Hi')
(3, 'Hi')
(4, 'Hi')
(5, 'Hi')
(6, 'Hi')
...
```