# Why do I run into an infinite loop without __contains__?

Tags: python, infinite-loop

The following code runs into an infinite loop:

```
class SubCommandMap:

    def __init__(self):
        self._command = dict()

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._command.get(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._command[key] = value

m = SubCommandMap()
" " in m   # <- why is this an infinite loop?
```

Of course this is an error. `m` was suppossed to be a different object of a different type.
But why does this end up in an infinite loop instead of throwing an exception?

I have added the following method:

```
    def __contains__(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Now I am getting an appropriate error message.

Are there other, similar cases where I need to be careful to avoid an infinite loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the absence of `__contains__` the `in` operator will use the `__getitem__` method you have defined to see if it gets the object you're looking for. It will pass every int in turn to `__getitem__` until it finds the item or the method raises an exception. If neither of those happens, you have an infinite loop.

Comment: Indeed, one fix could be to change `__getitem__` to use normal indexing instead of calling `dict.get`, so that bogus indexes would raise an `IndexError` instead of returning `None`.

Comment: ... and since the `dict.get(...)` in `__getitem__`  here will always return `None` - there's 
 never a truthy value

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are other similar cases.

- Trying to iterate over an object which implements `__getitem__` but not `__iter__` is an infinite loop if `__getitem__` does not throw an exception. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26611554/2828064).