# Why `__iter__` does not work when defined as an instance variable?

Tags: python, iteration, iterable

If I define the `__iter__` method as follows, it won't work:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__iter__ = lambda: iter('text')


for i in A().__iter__():
    print(i)

iter(A())
```

Result:

```
t
e
x
t
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\mytest.py", line 10, in <module>
    iter(A())
TypeError: 'A' object is not iterable
```

As you can see, calling `A().__iter__()` works, but `A()` is not iterable.

However if I define `__iter__` for the class, then it will work:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self):

        self.__class__.__iter__ = staticmethod(lambda: iter('text'))
        # or:
        # self.__class__.__iter__ = lambda s: iter('text')


for i in A():
    print(i)

iter(A())

# will print:
# t
# e
# x
# t
```

Does anyone know why python has been designed like this? i.e. why `__iter__` as instance variable does not work? Don't you find it unintuitive?

Comment: I think the way you try to do it in very unintuitive, why don't you just override __iter__ as a method ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019971/how-to-implement-iter-self-for-a-container-object-python

Comment: Seems to be an old-style vs new-style class issue. Your code does not work with new-style classes.

Comment: @PyNico In the particular case that I'm currently working on, I prefer to define `__iter__` inside `__init__` because it's implementation depends on the instantiation arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is done by design. You can find the thorough description here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup

Short answer: the special method must be set on the class object itself in order to be consistently invoked by the interpreter.

Long answer: the idea behind this is to speed up well-known constructions. In your example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__iter__ = lambda: iter('text')
```

How often are you going to write a code like this in real life? So, what Python does - it skips a dictionary lookup of the instance, i.e. `iter(A())` simply does not "see" that `self.__iter__`, which is actually `self.__dict__['__iter__']` in this case.

It also skips all the `__getattribute__` instance and metaclass lookup gaining a significant speedup.

Comment: I've rewritten the answer to make it more comprehensible. Please tell if you have any questions, or something is not clear.

Comment: This is probably also related to why `(1, 2, 3)[2]` is much more faster than direct calling of `(1, 2, 3).__getitem__(2)` (in the latter python also looks inside instance attributes). Great answer, thank you so much.