# How to delegate `__iter__` method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

I would like to delegate `__iter__` method for an iterable container.

```
class DelegateIterator:
    def __init__(self, container):
        attribute = "__iter__"
        method = getattr(container, attribute)
        setattr(self, attribute, method)

d = DelegateIterator([1,2,3])
for i in d.__iter__(): # this is successful
    print(i)
for i in d: # raise error
    print(i)
```

The output is

```
1
2
3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    for i in d:
TypeError: 'DelegateIterator' object is not iterable
```

Please let me know how to delegate `__iter__` method.

Comment: `__iter__` does now work when defined as an instance variable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346584/why-iter-does-not-work-when-defined-as-an-instance-variable

Answer (score 5):

Why overcomplicate things?

```
class DelegateIterator:
    def __init__(self, container):
        self.container = container

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.container)
```