# Is it reasonable to implement a "generator" for Keras' fit_generator method() without calling yield()?

Tags: python, keras, generator

I'm using Keras to train up a neural network, and I've reached the point where my data sets are getting bigger than the amount of RAM installed on my computer, so it's time to modify my training script to call model.fit_generator() instead of model.fit(), so that I don't have to load in all of the training and validation data into RAM at once.

I've made the modification, and AFAICT it is working fine, but there's one thing that is bothering me a little bit -- all of the example usages of fit_generator() I've seen online use Python's `yield` feature to store the generator's state.  I'm an old C++ programmer at heart and suspicious of features like `yield` that I don't entirely understand, and therefore I wanted to maintain my generator's state explicitly rather than implicitly, so instead I implemented my generator like this:

```
class DataGenerator:
   def __init__(self, inputFileName, maxExamplesPerBatch):
      self._inputFileName       = inputFileName
      self._maxExamplesPerBatch = maxExamplesPerBatch

      self._inputsFile = open(inputFileName, "rb")
      if (self._inputsFile == None):
         self._print("Couldn't open file %s to read input data" % inputFileName)
         sys.exit(10)

      self._outputsFile = open(inputFileName, "rb")   # yes, we're deliberately opening the same file twice (to avoid having to call seek() a lot)
      if (self._outputsFile == None):
         self._print("Couldn't open file %s to read output data" % inputFileName)
         sys.exit(10)

      headerInfo = struct.unpack("<4L", self._inputsFile.read(16))          
      if (headerInfo[0] != 1414676815):
         print("Bad magic number in input file [%s], aborting!" % inputFileName)
         sys.exit(10)

      self._numExamples   = headerInfo[1]  # Number of input->output rows in our data-file (typically quite large, i.e. millions)
      self._numInputs     = headerInfo[2]  # Number of input values in each row
      self._numOutputs    = headerInfo[3]  # Number of output values in row
      self.seekToTopOfData()

   def __len__(self):
      return (math.ceil(self._numExamples/self._maxExamplesPerBatch))

   def __next__(self):
      numExamplesToLoad = self._maxExamplesPerBatch
      numExamplesLeft   = self._numExamples - self._curExampleIdx
      if (numExamplesLeft < numExamplesToLoad):
         numExamplesToLoad = numExamplesLeft
      inputData  = np.reshape(np.fromfile(self._inputsFile,  dtype='<f4', count=(numExamplesToLoad*self._numInputs)),  (numExamplesToLoad, self._numInputs))
      outputData = np.reshape(np.fromfile(self._outputsFile, dtype='<f4', count=(numExamplesToLoad*self._numOutputs)), (numExamplesToLoad, self._numOutputs))
      self._curExampleIdx += numExamplesToLoad
      if (self._curExampleIdx == self._numExamples):
         self.seekToTopOfData()
      return (inputData, outputData)   # <----- NOTE return, not yield!!

   def seekToTopOfData(self):
      self._curExampleIdx = 0
      self._inputsFile.seek(16)
      self._outputsFile.seek(16+(self._numExamples*self._numInputs*4))

[...]

trainingDataGenerator   = DataGenerator(trainingInputFileName, maxExamplesPerBatch)
validationDataGenerator = DataGenerator(validationInputFileName, maxExamplesPerBatch)

model.fit_generator(generator=trainingDataGenerator, steps_per_epoch=len(trainingDataGenerator), epochs=maxEpochs, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data=validationDataGenerator, validation_steps=len(validationDataGenerator))
```

... note that my __next__(self) function ends with a `return` rather than `yield`, and that I'm storing the generator's state explicitly (via private-member-variables in the DataGenerator object) rather than implicitly (via `yield` magic).  This seems to work fine.

My question is, will this unusual approach introduce any non-obvious behavioral problems that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A superficial examination of your code checks out. When you write a generator function and call it the call returns a generator whose `__next__` method is typically repeatedly called by an iteration until it raises the `StopIteration` exception.

A generator is a special case of an iterator. Iterables like lists have an `__iter__` method that produce an iterator.

Unless you want to send values *into* your generator as well as get them out, your `DataGenerator` is a reasonable way to implement an iterator, but to write an iterable you'd need another class whose `__iter__` method returns an instance of `DataGenerator`.

The answers at [How to implement __iter__(self) for a container object (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019971/how-to-implement-iter-self-for-a-container-object-python) might also be helpful.